# Scala Option ||

Tags: scala, scala-option

I want to get the value of one of several Option in scala, like this:

```
def or(a:Option[Int], b:Option[Int]):Option[Int]=
    if (a.isDefined) a else b

val a= Option(1)
val b= Option(2)
or(a,b).get
```

but I wonder why isn't the `||` operator defined  for Option? Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use orElse.

```
scala> Some(1) orElse Some(2)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> (None: Option[Int]) orElse Some(2)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Scalaz 7, you can use `Tags.First` monoid:

```
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Tags.First('a'.some) |+| Tags.First('b'.some)
res0: scalaz.@@[Option[Char],scalaz.Tags.First] = Some(a)

scala> Tags.First(none[Char]) |+| Tags.First('b'.some)
res1: scalaz.@@[Option[Char],scalaz.Tags.First] = Some(b)

scala> Tags.First('a'.some) |+| Tags.First(none[Char])
res2: scalaz.@@[Option[Char],scalaz.Tags.First] = Some(a)
```

See [Option as Monoid](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Option+as+Monoid.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `orElse`.

```
val a = None
val b = Some("b")

a orElse b
```

returns Some("b")